# How do I integrate Unity and CodeCov (Using GitHub Actions)?

Tags: unity, testing, unit-testing, test-driven-development

GitHub actions attempt to upload my coverage reports to CodeCov, but I get an error. Below is my most recent GitHub Action code, and the error I'm receiving from CodeCov. Please let me know if there is any more information I can provide.

**Error**

```
Run codecov/codecov-action@v2
  with:
    name: CodeCov
    flags: automated
    token: ***
    files: coverage-results/**/*.xml
  env:
    UNITY_LICENSE: ***
==> linux OS detected
https://uploader.codecov.io/latest/linux/codecov.SHA256SUM
==> SHASUM file signed by key id 806bb28aed779869
==> Uploader SHASUM verified (330066ecce62f2cdcfd2fe1845095475f51bbad9649dce81ac7b663dc884bbef  codecov)
==> Running version latest
==> Running version v0.1.15
/home/runner/work/_actions/codecov/codecov-action/v2/dist/codecov -n CodeCov -Q github-action-2.1.0 -f coverage-results/**/*.xml -F automated -C 9d9656791bb5e390945821f1ecaae8a226b15aba
[2022-01-27T20:19:24.095Z] ['info'] 
     _____          _
    / ____|        | |
   | |     ___   __| | ___  ___ _____   __
   | |    / _ \ / _` |/ _ \/ __/ _ \ \ / /
   | |___| (_) | (_| |  __/ (_| (_) \ V /
    \_____\___/ \__,_|\___|\___\___/ \_/

  Codecov report uploader 0.1.15
[2022-01-27T20:19:24.108Z] ['info'] => Project root located at: /home/runner/work/Time-Bubble/Time-Bubble
[2022-01-27T20:19:24.108Z] ['info'] ->  Token found by environment variables
[2022-01-27T20:19:24.119Z] ['info'] Searching for coverage files...
[2022-01-27T20:19:24.133Z] ['error'] There was an error running the uploader: Error while cleaning paths. No paths matched existing files!
```

**GitHub Action**

```
name: Test with coverage
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]
    
env:
  UNITY_LICENSE: ${{ secrets.UNITY_LICENSE }}
    
jobs:

  testRunner:
    name: Test in ${{ matrix.testMode }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        testMode:
          - EditMode
          - PlayMode
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Create LFS file list
        run: git lfs ls-files -l | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort > .lfs-assets-id

      - name: Restore LFS cache
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        id: lfs-cache
        with:
          path: .git/lfs
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-lfs-${{ hashFiles('.lfs-assets-id') }}

      - name: Git LFS Pull
        run: |
          git lfs pull
          git add .
          git reset --hard

      - name: Restore Library cache
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: Library
          key: Library-test-project-${{ matrix.targetPlatform }}
          restore-keys: |
            Library-test-project-
            Library-

      - uses: game-ci/unity-test-runner@v2.0-alpha-5
        id: testRunner
        with:
          testMode: ${{ matrix.testMode }}
          checkName: ${{ matrix.testMode }} test results
          githubToken: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          customParameters: -debugCodeOptimization -enableCodeCoverage -coverageResultsPath ./coverage-results -coverageOptions generateAdditionalMetrics


      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: Test results (${{ matrix.testMode }})
          path: ${{ steps.testRunner.outputs.artifactsPath }}
          
  codeCov:
    needs: testRunner
    name: Submit to CodeCov
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Upload XML report to Codecov
        uses: codecov/codecov-action@v2
        with:
          name: CodeCov
          flags: automated
          token: ${{ secrets.CODECOV_TOKEN }}
          files: coverage-results/**/*.xml
          
      - name: Check for failure
        if: steps.CodeCov.outcome != 'success'
        run: exit 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. When revising your post, it's [not necessary to mark edits/updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127655/228147) - we can always look at the edit history if need to see changes.

Comment: @Pikalek thanks! Updated!

Comment: Sure, it's not a huge problem & the culture of sites varies from place to place. Somewhat related, if you find that your question is evolving significantly, (i.e. you solved it, but ran into a new problem), consider answering your own question with your solution & posting a new question. This allows other to benefit from your solution if they run into the previous situation & allows others to help with the new problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you're seeing

> [2022-01-27T20:19:24.133Z] ['error'] There was an error running the uploader: Error while cleaning paths. No paths matched existing files!

implies that either (1) the coverage file doesn't exist or that (2) it's not at the right location. Given that you seem to have a lot of control as to where that file is located, I'm going to assume that it's likely the first problem.

Taking a look at your `codeCov` job, it looks like it is only trying to upload coverage reports to Codecov. However, the job doesn't have access to that file because it isn't persisted across jobs.

**You can solve this by either combining the two jobs into one or using an artifact strategy presented [here](https://about.codecov.io/blog/uploading-code-coverage-in-a-separate-job-on-github-actions/) and adding a `download-artifact` step.**

One note, if you do end up doing `download-artifact` as the solution, I think you will still need to do an `actions/checkout@v2` step.

Comment: Because I'm running the Test Job in both PlayMode and EditMode, if I combined the CodeCov Job with the Test Job, would it try to upload it twice, or is there a way to insert it into that job but outside of that strategy matrix?

Comment: In my code, it seems I'm already uploading one artifact (for each test) with the test results. So I have to then also upload an artifact for the coverage, and then I can download that artifact and still checkout in the codecov test, correct? Just trying to make sure I fully understand.

Comment: If you combined the jobs, it would upload twice, once for PlayMode and once during EditMode. This won't be a problem from the Codecov side, as it will automatically combine reports. You could also take advantage of their [flag](https://docs.codecov.com/docs/flags) feature to separate out the two sets of coverage.
---

If you are going to stay with the upload/download artifact route, you will only need to checkout, download artifacts, and run the Codecov action.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, you've been fantastic, as has your colleague helping me with my ticket. May I ask you a few more GitHub actions related questions here https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133571/chat-about-github-actions?

Comment: Sorry @JShoe I didn't get a notification about this. If you drop into our [community boards](https://community.codecov.com), I'll be quicker to respond there.